# Failed to install pycharm on Ubuntu 16 - Could not initialize class java.awt.Color

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

Failed to install pycharm on Ubuntu 16 - got the following exception:  Could not initialize class java.awt.Color

Comment: This command line solved my problem: sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev

Answer (score 0):

This command line solved my problem:

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev